# Where to steal items to deconstruct?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In TESO, I have this technique to improve my blacksmithing rather fast:

1. find an closed door armory and get inside
2. steal all the weapons
3. log-out then log-back in
4. repeat steps 2 and 3 until your inventory is full
5. deconstruct everything and gain 1-2 levels of blacksmithing.

For blacksmithing, for instance, I found the Red Squall Armory in Wayrest.

Are there other closed-doors locations like that where you can steal in large batches

- light/medium armor?
- bows/staves/shields?

Note: the closed-door part is really important as if you mess up and get caught, you can continue your stealing without having the guards harassing you.

Comment: Note: This is on the edge to exploiting. Instead I'd just travel from armory to armory to "shop" some armor pieces.

Answer (score 5):

Sabyssa's Blacksmith, in Stormhaven, the first town from Glendura.

You can easily get away with stealing 15 or so weapons a login, with out bounty increase.

You can also smith, nearby.

Comment: Why the -1? Seems relevant.